# Use several table in a same controller in CakePhp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-3.0

I decided to pass on version 3 of CakePHP but I am stuck with a problem.

I have an `ORDER` table and a `PREPARATION` table (with an `order_id`) in my database. I defined in `Model > Table` the two tables, with a `hasMany('Orders')` in `PREPARATION`.

In my Orders controller, I want to record an entry on `PREPARATION`, I added the line `use App\Model\Table\PreparationsTable;` in my controller, but it tells me that `$this->Preparations` is a boolean so I deduce that the link is not made with the Preparations table, I tried with a find on my table `ARTICLES` but same error.

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution,

I add `$preparations = TableRegistry::get('Preparations');` and use `$preparations` instead of `$this->Preparations`. It works.
You have to add this `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` on top of your controller.